# How to keep safe some of the php files before sell

Tags: php, joomla2.5, encryption, ioncube

I am going to sell my products which contain the License key validation for a joomla site.So i need to encrypt some of my php files to preventing from hackers.I've been searching since the morning and haven't find any solution.Tried for ioncube software.It encrypt the file.But it could not decrypt for my server.What will be the best way to prevent some files from hackers ??

Comment: Are you selling GPL code?

Comment: @ValentinDespa Even if he was, that's not a violation of the GPL!

Answer (score 2):

All protection can be broken, you can only do your best to keep the honest people honest, and the people that don't care so much away from wanting to touch your code.

Ioncube is probably a good solution for this. The reason it doesn't work on your server is likely because you simply haven't included the module.

Another alternative to Ioncube is [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/). When you use Zend Guard, you need to install the [Zend Optimizer](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/runtime-decoders) onto the server, which is the runtime decoder. Most of the products come with this for better protection than simply encoding files on disk and decoding them, which is very easily beaten.

If your main issue is redistribution, write your licenses as such so that it becomes a legal issue rather than a code issue. This is why we have lawyers to write software license agreements.

Answer (score 1):

IonCube is great imho.
Have you installed the IonCube Loader on the server?

Get it here:
http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php

Answer (score 0):

You can make it harder for the other people.
http://blog.builtbyprime.com/php/tiny-php-a-fun-php-minifier
This is the only thing i would do if i where you.